# In Elastic search 2.4 sort is not working properly . it is always giving 1.7976931348623157e+308

Tags: elasticsearch

The distance sort was working fine in elasticsearch 1.7 but when i upgrade to 2.4

Sort Result is always giving 1.7976931348623157e+308

```
"sort": [
1.7976931348623157e+308
]
```

irrespective of geoPoint query

Comment: Post your search template, mapping, and some sample docs.

Comment: i got answer myself.. we need to use nested_path in our sort builder